# Windows 10 BSOD - msump64x64.sys

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bsod

I have a Surface Laptop 4 15" with AMD Ryzen 7 Processor, 16GB RAM and 512GB SSD

For the past few weeks, I have been getting Blue Screened by Windows with the fairly common:
`IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`

The driver in question according to the Blue Screen is `msump64x64.sys` which after some googling, doesn't appear to exist. I have tried running AMD's auto driver tool, ran Windows Updates and uninstalled any un-used software/drivers but it happens 1-2 times per day and is getting quite frustrating

Next step is hardware RMA with Microsoft but I want to rule out anything simple first

Thanks

Comment: Right click the `.sys` file and select Properties. Do you find any useful info in the Details tab? In which folder does it reside?

Comment: @harrymc I haven't been able to find the sys file in question, that is what it shows on the blue screen. Do you know whereabouts the file would be located?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. In the properties, comes up as Realtek USB FE/1GbE/2.5GbE/5GbE NIC Adapter

Comment: In Device Manager, it is linked to Surface Ethernet Adapter #2

Comment: What is the driver version? Does it have a name of a format similar to `RTL8156`?

Comment: Driver version is 10.45.20.308. This is in the events: `Device USB\VID_045E&PID_07C6\000001000000 was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.

Last Device Instance Id: VMBUS\{f8615163-df3e-46c5-913f-f2d2f965ed0e}\{4a3a96ea-4104-428a-9bec-ab5236b7c69f}
Class Guid: {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFFFFFFF122
Present: true
Status: 0xC0000719`

Comment: You could try installing [this version](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software). Does the device have a name of a format similar to `RTL` followed by a number?

Comment: Yes it does start RTL. I have ran the driver installation but it didn't change the version number. I will see if it's any better

Comment: Your device is the RTL8153 and is supported by the linked driver/

Comment: I uninstalled the driver from device manager while checking the option to delete it. It has been much better since with the original driver. The updater didn't change the version number so I don't think it had an effect. Thanks for your assistance :)